# Force redraw for DearImgui (cimgui-go)

Tags: go, imgui

I am using DearImgui bindings for golang (cimgui-go) to draw a window.

In one of the sub-windows, I am rendering a texture that is updated from a camera stream, acquired as individual images using OpenCV (gocv.io).

The goroutine that acquires the images notifies the DearImgui thread via a channel when a new image has arrived. The DearImgui thread then creates a texture from it and draws it with `imgui.ImageV`.

This kind of works if the window is focused and receiving input (e.g. moving the mouse cursor) but the render loop stops redrawing as soon as the window goes out of focus or no user input is available.

Are there any flags I can provide to DearImgui to force redraw, regardless of user input?